# Three headings on same line HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get three headings on the same line in HTML. This may not be the best way to go about things, so please inform me if it isn't. The application is a mock restaurant page and I want to display menu headings such as: "Entrees", "Drinks", "Desserts" where entrees is far left, drinks is centered, and desserts is far right. I've tried floating which worked for entrees and desserts but I'm not sure that's the correct approach. Text-align causes them to stack which I don't want and using an inline or inline-block also doesn't seem to be the correct solution. I'm fairly new to this so this could be lack of knowledge rearing it's head. Thank you for your time.

```
.menuHeadings {
    display: inline-block;
}

<div class ="menuHeadings">
    <h2>Entrees Desserts Drinks</h2>
</div>
```

The above gets me on the same line. If I separate the headings, they no longer appear on the same line, but I can use the text-align property, however, they're stuck to the same vertical block. I want to be able to do something similar to a text align left, center, right, for each one of these and keep them all on the same line. I've tried display inline and a few other things to no avail.

This is what I want it to look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uud0j.jpg

Comment: Please provide your **code**

Comment: @koder613 and/or a sketch of the desired result

Comment: Sorry about that. Added. I can still provide a sketch if that would show the desired result better.

Comment: use `display: flex` for the container and leave the headers as they are block elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Flexbox** is the solution.

Grid would be overwhelming for such a simple arrangement.

```css
.heading{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width:100%;
  font-size: 34px;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding: 0 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <p>Entrees</p>
  <p>Drinks</p>
  <p>Desserts</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is precisely what I'm looking for and short. I tried flex earlier but couldn't produce a good result. I tried with paragraphs and they stacked rather than displaying as a row, as yours does. Can you give insight into this? I think I'm lacking more on HTML/CSS 'fundamentals'. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: And a follow up to that question: Since <p> are defined as block elements, does containing them in a flexbox that flexes as a row override their default displaying on a newline for each <p>?

Comment: you need to define the direction of flex box i.e. flex-direction: row. The default value is 'column' and that's why your content was stacking on instead of expanding in row.

Comment: flexbox treats all immediate children as the same irrespective of their display property(other than none) and lays it out as per the configuration you provide via flex CSS attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .grid-container {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 72px;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            gap: 0px 0px;
            grid-template-areas:
                "Entrees Drinks Desserts ."
        }

        .Entrees {
            grid-area: Entrees;
        }

        .Drinks {
            grid-area: Drinks;
        }

        .Desserts {
            grid-area: Desserts;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="Entrees">Entrees</div>
        <div class="Drinks">Drinks</div>
        <div class="Desserts">Desserts</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Grid would resolve the issue, but it will be overwhelming for such a simple use problem and extra class + css.

Comment: I like this one, but I agree with Makvana, it seems like a little much.

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap you can achieve this by doing wrap in container class and then use d-flex,justify-content-between,align-items-centerenter code here

Comment: Hi, unless I msised soemthing, the Op never emntioned Bootstrap. Therefor your anwser might not even apply here. Please do not refer to methods the OP might cant even use.